# How can I take two lists and return the intersection of the sets in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, set-intersection

How can I find the intersection of two lists in python? I've tried it with  the in operator but am unsure as to how I do it without.

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
b = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
set(a) & set(b)
```

This should return [4, 8]

Comment: What is wrong with using the operator?

Comment: "I know how to do *X*, but how can I do it without using *feature that is designed to do X*?"

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your lists to sets, and then call `intersection`.  A Python [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) has `intersection` as a built-in method.

```
s1 = set(a)
s2 = set(b)
a.intersection(b)
# set([4,8])
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can get your intersection by using the example like below.

> Intersection is already a first class part of set, you can directly use it

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
b = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]
set(a).intersection(b)
```

The sets module provides classes for constructing and manipulating unordered collections of unique elements.Computing standard math operations on sets such as intersection, union etc.